# My array sorting program is weird in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

So I'm new to programmation and I tried to do an array sorting algorithm in Python that would give the first greatest value and the second one :

```
l = [2,3,3]
first = 0
second = 0
for i in range(len(l)) :
    if l[i] > first :
        second = first
        first = l[i]
    elif l[i] > second & l[i] != first :
        second = l[i]
print(first, second)
```

Weirdly, when I run the program, it gives me "3 3" instead of "3 2" and I then understood that it was considering the second 3 as the second greatest value, but I don't want it to be registered as a other value than the first 3.
What's even more weirder is that it is actually fixed when I put this :
`elif l[i] > second & l[i] == first :`
instead of this : `elif l[i] > second & l[i] != first :`
I tried to interpret the code in my head and when I get to the second "3", I don't understand why the `second = l[i]` part of the code is running because it means that 3 is not equal to 3 so.. However, this part doesn't execute (I think) when 3 is equal to 3.
So my problem is actually fixed, but I don't understand why and some explanations would be great as I am new to programmation and I maybe don't understant well the operators.

Comment: Use `and` (logical and), not `&` (bitwise and).